# How to theme snap Qt applications?

Tags: themes, snap

On Ubuntu 16.04, the Qt apps installed with snap are ugly and not themed. How to apply the GTK theme of Ubuntu to snap Qt apps ? The trick to use Qt5 configuration from [web8udpate](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/11/configure-qt5-application-style-icons.html) don't work. Below, for example KeepassXC (Qt 5) installed from snap :

[image: snap Qt apps not themed]

Comment: Not sure. You could try opening an Issue against [the KeePassXC GitHub](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/issues) since they maintain the snap (unless you're the snapcrafter yourself (lol), in which case I'd suggest opening a [snapcraft forum topic](https://forum.snapcraft.io/c/snap).

Comment: This is also a problem with the VLC snap